# Can't Submit App to App Store: "Sending API Usage to iTunes Connect" either times out or loses connection

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, app-store-connect

I request your help with this as I have been fighting with this since last night. I have googled for hours and I can't seem to find a solution to this so I am starting to fall for desperation.

Basically, I submitted an app last week. It got rejected because of a small mistake of my part. I want to resubmit it now, but the app won't upload. I need to note I have reconfigured my network since then but I'm sure all ports are open and that nothing should be getting on the way of my app being submitted.

Most of the fixes I have attempted to do come from other SO questions. Since nothing works, I am starting to think it's an issue with Apple, but at the same time I doubt they would leave this error unnoticed for over 15 hours now.

[image]

Above is an screenshot of what I get when I try upload an app using the Application Loader. The same error shows up from Organizer if I leave it running long enough. When I use XCode, I get a Connection Timed Out error.

Amongst the solutions I have tried:

1. Restart Xcode.
2. Restart my Mac.
3. Restart my router and modem.
4. Gone Xcode > Contents > Applications > Application Loader > Contents > MacOS > itms > java > lib - Opened net.properties with TextEdit and changed the line # https.proxyPort=443 to https.proxyPort=80
5. Went to preferences and left only DAV checked.
6. Built my app with a different certificate and provision profile.

Finally, I am using an iMac, so answers in the lines of "go to your nearest library and use their Wi-Fi" are not really feasable.

I am open to new ideas to try.

Comment: I think there is a problem with Apple servers, not your Mac.
I'm having the same problem and my app just magically published. I'm trying any kind of tricks since yesterday. Maybe you should wait :( You can't do anything while Apple is in control.

Comment: Hi, you have their system status website: http://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/ but it doesn't report any problem. You cannot probably go to an Internet cafe, but you could buy a 3G usb stick or connect through your iPhone / Android / ... tethering, etc. You have many options that don't solve your network problem but do solve your problem with the submission, especially if the binary is not a big one and you have 3G tethering capabilities.

Comment: I'm torn apart between thinking it's a problem with Apple or my Mac. In the end I sent the binary to my brother's MacBook pro and submitted it from there... It seemed to go fine, but awfully slow even for my connection. Either way, I solved my case. Good luck with yours!

Comment: I thought my submission was stuck at the point, but it turns out it was just going very slowly.  Sometimes patience is the solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like it is a trial and error kind of thing with me. For starters, my iMac never succeeds sending my app to iTunes. But my MacBook Pro does. With Application loader.

If the process is stuck in "Sending iTunes Usage to iTunes Connect" for over 15 Minutes, I force-quit Application Loader and open it again. It takes around 10 minutes for me to get past that stage.

Then comes the "authenticating with iTunes Connect" step, which takes around 10 minutes as well. If it goes for over 15 minutes in that step, then I have to force-quit.

These tips may not help everybody but it seems to be my case...

Answer (score 8):

I have the same! I have tried with other network sources, but negative result. But i solved this with Force Quit Aplication Loader when it shows you issue. I hope it helps to U.

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't think to try this, but it worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Cheeses! - force quit and restart Application Loader also just worked for me :)  ( v 2.9 )

Comment: Yes - that did it for me as well (had 15 unsucessfull tries with both XCode and Application Loader)

Comment: Worked for me as well. I wonder what is the equivalent for Xcode submission

Comment: Failed repeatedly with xCode (tried restarting), but worked first time with Application Loader.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The moment you see this error.Just Hold CMD key and press Q. Then try again. You don't have to switch your network sources. It looks like App is spawning multiple threads to upload your IPA.

Comment: **CMD+Q** is for Quitting the app. Isn't it?